# XmlHttpRequest Auth in javascript to CMIS Server

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cmis

I have a server A which provides (via *HTTPS*) a form to upload to an other server B (via *HTTP*). Server B is a CMIS Server.

This form contain an input file with the file to upload.
The following function submit my form.

```
function AJAXSubmit (oFormElement) {        
      if (!oFormElement.action) { return; }
      var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
      oReq.onload = ajaxSuccess;
      if (oFormElement.method.toLowerCase() === "post") {
        oReq.open("post", oFormElement.action, false, "test", "test");
        oReq.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("test" + ":" + "test"));
        oReq.send(new FormData(oFormElement));
      } else {
        // For GET method but that doesn't interest me
      }
    }
```

And next the response header I get.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:private, max-age=0
Content-Language:fr
Content-Length:1008
Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8
Date:Tue, 05 Aug 2014 08:18:45 GMT
Server:Apache-Chemistry-OpenCMIS/0.11.0
WWW-Authenticate:Basic realm="CMIS"
```

And I still have a 401 - unauthorized error. I think that's not a cross-domain error because I resolved this. So I have two question :

1. What is the good way to auth to a (Cmis) fileshare server?
2. Is there a particular way to do that for a file cmis upload? Because there a lot of subject on the web and any solution work for me.

PS: I see that Chrome have error on the send method and send an OPTION request. IE send a POST request but have error on the open request.

**Edit :** 
The localhost_access_log is the only which provide something to that action :

```
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [05/Aug/2014:14:13:19 +0200] "OPTIONS /chemistry-opencmis-server-fileshare-0.11.0/atom/test/content/402881c447a500300147a616734303b3?id=LzQwMi84ODEvYzQ0LzdhNS8wMDMvMDAxLzQ3YS82MTYvNzM0LzMwMy9iMy80MDI4ODFjNDQ3YTUwMDMwMDE0N2E2MTY3MzQzMDNiMw== HTTP/1.1" 401 1008
```

Comment: Did you check the logs on the server? Especially for hints that you might've got the authentication details wrong

Comment: There is a whitespace missing. Replace "Basic" with "Basic ".

Comment: @FlorianMüller Sorry it's an error when I copy.

Comment: @Gagravarr I add the log in the question in 30s.

Comment: I think you're generating the Authorization header incorrectly, that's what it looks like from the log

Comment: Is it a problem from my JS code or from the server side?

Comment: JavaScript side almost certainly

Comment: @Gagravarr I just thinking that Server A is used with HTTPS and Server B is used with simple HTTP request. Can it be the reason?